# These creatures eat human fear - how do they justify it?

Tags: biology, science-fiction, horror, fear

[Humans have particular pheromones in their sweat that represents fear](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0956797620970548#:%7E:text=There%20is%20evidence%20that%20psychological,to%20the%20sender%27s%20internal%20state.) (very interesting study - tldr: there are particular chemical odors emitted through sweat when humans are fearful that can be subconsciously detected by other humans). Knowing this, and loving the horror genre, I had an idea for a possibly-cliched but nonetheless interesting creature that, like [how humans need vitamin B12 but only in very small (microgram-sized) amounts](https://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements-vitamin-b12/art-20363663), needs the chemicals specific to these fear pheromones in order to survive.

In context, the species in question is a sub-K1 civilization that originates from a star system containing two distinct forms of life, with this "feareater" species evolving on an inner rock giant and another species evolving on an outer gas giant's moon. The latter species (the "angels?") lived on a Titan-like moon and become technologically advanced much faster than the feareater species for social reasons. Early into their interactions, the technologically-inferior feareater species began to take issue with the angels' superior cell phones and a terrorist faction started a war between the two species, eventually resulting in the irradiation of the feareater homeworld. Feareaters fleeing their radioactive home planet stole angels' ships (which are FTL-capable) and jumped across the galaxy to escape the angels who were chasing after them. However, they don't have a proper food source as the ships' gardens were not designed with the proper systems to raise crops that the feareaters could eat, so they resort to finding worlds that could host them and farming as much of their food as they could before inevitably having to get up and run from the angels again.

Naturally, one of the planets the feareaters come across is Earth, and being feareaters that require the fear pheromones in humans to survive, they are intrigued by the concept of using humans as sources of this chemical, as it is extraordinarily difficult to find a planet that can properly host the food that the feareaters usually cultivate to get this chemical in their diets. But feareaters, despite being horrifying to humans and literally feeding on human fear, aren't monsters; they're a sapient species that's just trying to survive. But Earth is a one-time opportunity that turns out to be very rare throughout the universe, and staying there would inevitably attract the angels which would result in the destruction of the feareaters who choose to eat human fear.

**So, the question: how does a sapient, intelligent, non-awful species like the feareaters justify subjugating humans to produce the chemical they need to survive?** They have a sense of morality and don't want to subjugate a species, and also don't really want to have to deal with the angels who'll come after them if they stay in one place, but for some reason, they choose to stay in our Solar System and terrorize us to produce their vitamins - what motivates the feareaters to do such a thing?

Comment: This chemical may be produced by fearful humans, but it doesn't mean that other life forms will produce it for the same reason, if they produce it at all.  It may have an entirely different purpose on other worlds.

Comment: Is there a reason they cannot or don't want to synthesize the chemical?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. How exactly does this eliminate the Feareaters' need to grow crops? I get that human fear supplies this one critical nutrient, but presumably the Feareaters still need to put something solid in their mouths so they don't starve to death. Or perhaps it's like Star Trek, where they have "replicators" that make food out of basically nothing, except this is the one chemical the replicators can't make because [insert reason here]?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm assuming; the stolen angels' ships have replicator-like technology that can grow *some* food but not any that have the required nutrients (the human fear pheromone in particular) that the feareaters don't need much of but will die without. The reasoning is just that the replicators are very complicated technology, and the angels didn't originally consider other species' dietary requirements when building them.

Comment: Trying, and failing, not to bring up the typographic meaning of justification.

Comment: By the smell of ammonia I guess?

Comment: Suggested change: it's not food. It's an illegal drug. Goes around a lot of issues such as "why don't they synthetize it?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, this answer is going to be a partial frame challenge, partial not.

First question - why do they need to subjugate humanity? If they feed off of the chemical in the air, then all they need is a cunning disguise (some form of Fake moustache) and general proximity to Humans and they are good to go.

Now - for the Angels in your story - if you didn't need Humans to survive, why would you put up with Humanity? We are a Brutal, Murderous race with the ability to inflict extreme cruelty when pissed off enough - The Angels might look at us (not knowing the Feareaters are on the planet) and go 'Stuff that for a joke' and move on.

**For the fun part of the Answer**

There are many ways in which a Fear Eater could get a regular supply of Fear:

- Working in a Hospital (Fear of Death)
- Working in a Theme park
- Working in an Airline (Fear of Flying)
- Zookeeper for the Arachnid display

you get the point - there are many ways in which Humans *actively seek out fear* and so all a Feareater would need to do is make sure they are in close proximity to such an enterprise - and free lunch.

*If you want to add elements of social critique to your story*

The Feareaters start a Social Media company and News Organization that behaves curiously similar to our current companies that actively promote stories and content that preys on peoples anxieties and fears - they justify it by saying 'The humans do it to themselves voluntarily anyway'

*If you want a different element of social critique*

The Feareaters simply sow seeds of prejudice, heightening fears about foreigners, other cultures etc. etc. and deliberately provoke pre-existing societal tensions in order to create a veritable smorgasboard.

Upcoming Jewish holiday? The Feareaters vandalize a synagogue with mid-century german imagery.
Upcoming School board election? The Feareaters plant highly sexualized material in the school library
etc.

*Want to talk about Xenophobia and refugees?*

The Feareaters formally request Asylum on earth - *their mere prescence is enough to generate sufficient fear in people for them to feed*

There's a bunch more ways you can go - depending on how you want your story/world to play out.

Comment: I don't think the 'fear' that is talked about in xenophobia and the like is the same fear that leads to the adrenaline and other chemical heavy sweat that those feareaters are eating. The airline and zookeeper ideas however seem really great to have that exact fearful sweat bein generated on a daily basis

Comment: @datacube - I know what you mean - the immediate fear of death vs general discomfort - however the reason I raised it is, depending on the Authors desires - you can have a lot of options for social commentary.

Answer (score 7):

Part of the question depends on numbers and true needs of the Feareater.

If there are too many of the Feareaters, then they would end up needing Earth's entire population to sustain them.  Some cold stay and try to make Earth their home, but most of them, and us, will be yeeted from the planet to be fear batteries and cheap labour.

If there's only a tiny handful of them, then they could just be dead when they try to abduct a human unless they are highly resistant to bullets.  Or any other number of weapons we have developed.

Three options that don't involve the wholesale subjugation of the planet are below.

#### Willing Horror

See, some of us like to be scared.  Some of us like horror and that thrill of fear.  Those people, so long as they could live their lives otherwise, would be essentially a willing food source for these Feareaters.  They would go to the haunted houses, the horror shows, and the spooky things to be scared and the Feareaters would have a good source of Vitamin Fear.  It might not be pure and unadulterated Fear, but it should suffice.

They could infiltrate and take over the spooky spots in the world and people would come to them so long as they only proved scary and not violent.  I mean how many stories of cryptids are out there that are vague and scary that they could possibly fill?

Alternatively, if they understand how human fear works and more importantly how to *make* us scared, they could have a semi-lucrative market in a burgeoning horror industry.

If the number of Feareaters are small enough, then there may even be enough willing humans to keep them fed.  Perhaps not to any excesses, but quite possibly fed enough to live comfortably.

This type of more symbiotic scenario works best if the only thing needed is the fear pheromones.

#### Store Bought is Fine

Another alternative is that if the Feareaters descend upon our modern world, as they stalk us, they may see some of us humans taking pills for conditions that they don't understand.  Kidnapping a few of us and interrogating them (also a free dinner) may reveal that some of us humans take medicines to compensate for things that our body doesn't make -- like vitamins.

Armed with that knowledge and the knowledge that they need a specific chemical to optimally survive, us humans could be ... convinced ... to determining what specific fear chemical they need as a vitamin and then figuring out how to synthesize it in enough quantity to keep the Feareaters alive without them terrorizing the galaxy.

This may require subjugating a sustainable population of us humans to continue to make the chemicals on their spacecraft so they don't have to keep coming back so often, but see the previous point about willing subjects.

If you can't make your own vitamins, store bought is fine!

Note:  This is strictly dependent on the Feareaters only needing the pheromone chemical to survive, and not any mental energies that are radiated with the fear or something else similarly non-physical.

#### Space Orcs!

Humans are Space Orcs -- there's plenty of pages about that on the Internets

If there is enough room on the ships, the Feareaters could likely just pull up on Earth, advertise an Awesome Space Adventure (TM) and probably recruit a sustainable human population from those that want to go for all of their varied reasons.

Given that they are constantly on the run, and may or may not know to much about the spacecraft that they have stolen to run from the angels, this adventure is an forever chase chock full of Oh Shit (TM) moments, guaranteed to cause at least one hapless ensign to evacuate their bowels in fear.  Much to the Feareater's delight.

Plus all the malfunctions that could arise that could kill them all, the aliens that may or may not want to bed, wed, or behead the crew, and you have not only a crew that can keep maintenance of the ship, but their fear throughout this adventure would be delicious.

Is this subjugation?  Technically yes, as it is the Feareaters that hold the power at least in the beginning.  But we humans bond with other living beings, so bonding with them and having a good ol' scary time is not outside the realm of possibility.

And if the Feareaters pilot their FTL craft a bit close to a star to spook the humans, well they're just hungry ...

Answer (score 5):

### There are non-"destructive" means of harvesting the fear.

No species is a monolith. Some of them will surely rely on classic methods of stalking/threatening and maybe even killing humans. However there are plenty of ways they could what they need without humans even knowing.

#### Horror movie screenings in special theaters.

Construct a two story theater, on the bottom/basement story you have an olfactory observatory. On the floor above you have vents below the seats of a normalish theater. Then just screen scary movies, and during the scary bits pump air into the upper theater filtering the air down to the floor below where the fear eaters have come to ... eat fear.

#### "air conditioned" roller coaster rides.

Specially designed "thrill rides" could be self-contained with air filters to pull out and store the phearamone for later collection and distribution. Probably not desirable as "fresh" like in a movie theater but still enough to sustain.

#### Halloween Scare Houses

They'd probably need costumes to appear "less" scary but working in a one of the seasonal attractions would give access to some of the freshest food for a fear eater.

#### Rescue Workers/EMT

With a good enough disguise if they took on roles in Search and Rescue and emergency medical teams they could do good, while also getting front row seat access to quite a bit of fear.

Answer (score 2):

You've given the answer yourself: they need to survive. That's a hell of a justification for just about anything. What's the alternative? Die? Do you think many humans would choose dying over subjugating other humans?

Comment: And for further sophist justification if that makes the feareaters uncomfortable in itself, then they can tell each other "It's either us, or the humans.  Humans would do it to each other, so they are inherently sub-feareater and not worth the same consideration as us.  Just another type of animal really.  Quite a disgusting one."

Answer (score 1):

What if the creatures, by eating human fear, absorbed it out of the humans, so that the humans' fear was relieved? Since the creatures have moral standards, maybe they could be subjugating the humans in order to take away their fear, like for the greater good.